# Limiting extra parameters on an MVC route resulting in error

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

I have a results page that can have parameters on the end of a url.  These parameters represent category and filters and are used for SEO links on the site or in emails.  We currently only allow 4 parameters in route.config (the category and 3 optional filters).  So this would be a valid url:

http://myshoppingsite.com/results/dresses/red/black/blue

```
routes.MapRoute("ResultsCanonicalFiltered", "results/{Categoy}/{Filter1}/{Filter2}/{Filter3}", new { controller = "Results", action = "Index", Category = UrlParameter.Optional, Filter1 = UrlParameter.Optional, Filter2 = UrlParameter.Optional, Filter3 = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

We have seen instances where end users will add additional parameters resulting in the following error:

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Not a valid url:
http://myshoppingsite.com/results/dresses/red/black/blue/purple

My question is this, how cqn we prevent this error if a user adds an extra parameter to the end of a url that was originally clicked from within pages of our site or, as is often the case, an email ad campaign?

Thanks,

Rhonda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this, in case anyone else ever has this issue, they may find this useful.

I can add a "wildcard" parameter to the end of my route (I called it CatchAll) like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("ResultsCanonicalFiltered", "results/{Categoy}/{Filter1}/{Filter2}/{Filter3}/{*CatchAll}", new { controller = "Results", action = "Index", Category = UrlParameter.Optional, Filter1 = UrlParameter.Optional, Filter2 = UrlParameter.Optional, Filter3 = UrlParameter.Optional, CatchAll = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Also add it as a property/parameter of the ActionResult in the controller, then we can just ignore that parameter.

With the following url, the CatchAll parameter would contain the value purple/yellow/orange which we would just ignore.

http://myshoppingsite.com/results/dresses/red/black/blue/purple/yellow/orange

And there you have it.  It may not be the most elegant solution but it works and avoids customers getting that error message.

Rhonda